# Jquery Datepicker Set Value From String

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am getting a string date from cookie which returns like this format `2017-11-16`. My datepicker dateformat is `D, M d, yy` e.g `Thu, Apr 27, 2017`.

if I just set it as `$("#m_checkin").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", "2017-11-16");` datepicker functions stop working and it just set `2017-11-16` as an input value. How can I format my date to my datepicker dateformat?

https://jsfiddle.net/n6dokkty/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse date before set date to particular format.
You can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/r1nm5h7k/

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"});
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("setDate", $.datepicker.parseDate( "yy-mm-dd", "2017-11-16" ));
```

**ref : https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate**

Comment: I followed your way but at this time, functions stopped working after setting the date(last line). I added jsfiddle link in my question so you can check it out. 
https://jsfiddle.net/n6dokkty/

Comment: you need to include the jquery and jquery-ui for this to work. Check this -
 https://jsfiddle.net/arvinddhakad/r1nm5h7k/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), which is a javascript date/time library. With that, you can easily convert between dates of different format.

`string newDate = moment(currentDate, currentFormatString).format(newFormatString)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to `setDate` with `Date` object instead of string (to avoid date format issues like you face currently).

So you have to change your code like below:

```
$("#m_checkin").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date(2017,11,16));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! For future reference, you have to place a blank line before any lines of code for the format parser to pick them up.